# how to query al least 2 rows that have int value over than a specific value

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql query:
I have two tables, scores and classes

```
`scores`
name  class    score
jack  english  81
jason english  76
alan  english  81
alan  math     100
alan  physics  90

`classes`
class
english
math
physics
```

How do I query for:

1. the student names that have at least 2 different classes with score over than 80?
   the above example should return `alan` only, because `jack` and `jason` both only have 1 class score above 80.
2. the student names that have average score over 80, and min score over than 60. (and if a student does not have a score to a class, it counts 0, for example in above case, jack scored 0 in physics, so his min score is not 75 for math, it is 0 for physics)

Thanks

Comment: Could Jack ever have more than one entry in the `SCORES` table for "math"?

Comment: no, that will not hanppen

Comment: Show desired output for (2).

Comment: only alan, because both jack and jason scored 0 on physics (no entry), so their mins are not over 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query 1

```
SELECT name
FROM scores
WHERE score > 80
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT class) > 1
```

Query 2

```
SELECT names.name
FROM classes
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT name
             FROM scores ) names
LEFT JOIN scores ON classes.class = scores.class
                AND names.name = scores.name
GROUP BY names.name
HAVING AVG(COALESCE(score, 0)) > 80
   AND MIN(COALESCE(score, 0)) > 60;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e681fd5116edca39a7b91969f424c272)

Comment: the first one works, the second one does not, because if a score does not have a corresponding class, it counts 0 score, I updated the description for the second one.

Comment: yes, when calculating avg, it also need to consider (no class -> score=0) case.

Comment: I just realized the second query returns both jason and alan, however, since jason does not have a physics score, so his min score is 0 for physics, he should not be returned, how would I adjust this. thanks

Comment: I tried with left join, but it is still return jason.

Comment: I see what your answer is doing, it works now, thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Query1:

`SELECT` name`FROM`scores`WHERE`score`> 80 GROUP BY`name `HAVING COUNT(`class`) > 1;`

Query2:

SELECT `name` FROM `scores`
WHERE `score` > 60
GROUP BY `name`
HAVING AVG(`score`) > 80;

Comment: `scores (name, class)` is defined to be unique nowhere.